# proper link left/right assets for rigging (2.8)

Tags: rigging, vertex-groups

Can you help me understand the error of my ways?

In 2.8

1. have a standard character with nicely detailed & mirrored left/right sides.
2. The character is rigged with vertex groups.
3. Arm.L and Arm.R are *WERE* linked duplicates - but I broke the link to assign left/right vertex groups.
4. If I now want to modify an arm, I have to relink the objects (ctrl-L), modify them, unlink them and reset the vertex groups (manually?).

So, point 4 obviously can't be the right way to go about this. In fact it's only manageable since the model+armature is quite simple.

Q) How do you keep assets separated (say a rigid armour piece) while using it in an armature modifier or "child-of"-bone constraint.

Thanks for your time.

Marc